# Why doesn't is_class<T> work in this code segment?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

Trying to use is_class in the following segment (stripped down from a larger one), but it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename U, typename = void>
struct xxxU_Impl
{
    static void xxxU_push (const U& value);
};

template<typename U> void xxxU_push (const U& value) { xxxU_Impl<U>::xxxU_push (value); }

template<typename U>
struct xxxU_Impl<U *, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<U>::value>::type>
{
    static void xxxU_push (const U *& value) { }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    int mFoo;
};

int main () {
    Foo * pFoo = new Foo;

    xxxU_push<Foo *>(pFoo);
}
```

This is with gcc v4.7.2 on cygwin with  gcc -std=c++11 test.cpp command line.

The output is:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void xxxU_push(const U&) [with U = Foo*]':
test.cpp:26:23:   required from here
test.cpp:9:63: error: no matching function for call to 'xxxU_Impl<Foo*, void>::xxxU_push(Foo* const&)'
test.cpp:9:63: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:14:17: note: static void xxxU_Impl<U*, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<_Tp>::value>::type>::xxxU_push(const U*&) [with U = Foo]
test.cpp:14:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Foo* const' to 'const Foo*&'
```

**

### Update

:**
Here's the modified code with annotations which IMHO show that the types are now identical. Still, I'm getting a compile error.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename U, typename = void>
struct xxxU_Impl
{
    static void xxxU_push (const U  & value);   // U=Foo*:  const Foo* & value ==
                                                //          Foo const * & value
};

template<typename U> void xxxU_push (const U  & value)  // U=Foo*:  const Foo* & value ==
                                                        //          Foo const * & value
{ xxxU_Impl<U>::xxxU_push (value); }

template<typename U>
struct xxxU_Impl<U *, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<U>::value>::type>
{
    static void xxxU_push (U const * & value) { }   // U=Foo:   Foo const * & value
};

class Foo
{
public:
    int mFoo;
};

int main () {
    Foo* pFoo = new Foo;

    xxxU_push<Foo*>(pFoo);
}
```

What's wrong?

Thx,
D

PS A similar scheme with is_enum works w/o a hitch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `std::is_class<>` trait is working fine, and the compiler is pretty much telling you what the problem is:

> test.cpp:14:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from `Foo* const` to `const Foo*&`

You are invoking your function template this way:

```
xxxU_push<Foo *>(pFoo);
```

Which means that `U` will be `Foo*`. Now the function signature:

```
template<typename U>
void xxxU_push (const U& value)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
template<typename U>
void xxxU_push (U const& value)
```

And after replacing `Foo*` for `U` you get this:

```
void xxxU_push (Foo* const& value)
```

Therefore, `value` is a constant reference to a pointer to a `Foo`. Inside the function, you instantiate your class template this way:

```
xxxU_Impl<U>::xxxU_push (value);
```

Which is, when substituting `Foo*` for `U` again:

```
xxxU_Impl<Foo*>::xxxU_push (value);
```

Now your class template specialization is defined this way:

```
template<typename U>
struct xxxU_Impl<U *, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<U>::value>::type>
{
    static void xxxU_push (const U *& value) { }
};
```

If you are instantiating it with `Foo*` as a template argument, `U` will be deduced to be `Foo`, which *is* a class type. Therefore, your class template gets instantiated without failures (not sure this is what you want, but this is definitely what happens), and in particular the `xxxU_push()` function gets instantiated this way:

```
 static void xxxU_push (const Foo *& value) { }
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
 static void xxxU_push (Foo const*& value) { }
```

Can you see the difference? On the calling site you have a constant reference to a non-constant pointer, here you have a non-constant reference to a constant pointer! These two types are different, and the compiler complains that it cannot convert the argument.

You could fix your error, for instance, by changing the signature of `xxxU_push()` as follows:

```
static void xxxU_push (U * const& value) { }
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

After this change, you can see the whole thing compiling [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4sAas7%2469).

**UPDATE:**

As a follow-up from the comments, it turns out you necessarily want the `static` member function `xxxU_push()` to accept a pointer to `const`:

```
 static void xxxU_push (Foo const*& value) { }
```

In this case, you will have to make a decision: you cannot pass a `Foo*` to a function which accepts a non-constant *reference* to a `const` pointer. You can, however, drop the reference:

```
 static void xxxU_push (Foo const* value) { }
```

This is a first possibility to make your program compile. The second possibility is to change the call site so that it provides a pointer to `const`:

```
int main () {
    Foo * pFoo = new Foo;
    Foo const* pConstFoo = pFoo;
    xxxU_Impl<Foo*>::xxxU_push(pConstFoo);
//                             ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Since I want the parameter to be a variable pointer to a constant value passed by reference, I changed the implementation when the type is a class to: static void xxxU_push (U const * & value) { }. This now, following your logic, is identical to the calling signature. Still I'm, getting an error that no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Foo* const' to 'const Foo*&'

Comment: @qwer1304: Your comment got cut. Anyway, I'm glad this helped!

Comment: Not entirely; see the comment tail above.

Comment: @qwer1304: Of course, because `U const*&` is the same as `const U*&`. You have just changed the place of `const`, but not the type. Those two things are equivalent, so it makes sense that you are having the same trouble as before. If you want a pointer to const, then you need to change the calling function so that the proper type is passed

Comment: Since const is part of the signature, I ended up creating two templates, one with and the other without the const. The compiler picks up happily the correct one and things work. Thx